# Youtube API что использовать

Tags: java, google-api, youtube-api

Надо работать с youtube api, начал гуглить и такая непонятка.

Есть два мануала по работе с youtube api из java –
[YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/developers_guide_java#-) и [YouTube → Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java)

Причем везде используются разные библиотеки, в первом примере **com.google.gdata**, во втором - **com.google.api**, я в замешательстве.

По какому мануалу работать чтобы потом не мучиться? Кстати, на второй пример есть еще *maven* зависимости, на первый пока нашел только *jar* файлы в их *git* репозитории

Answer (score 5, accepted):

com.google.gdata (v2) - устарел - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java

Поэтому рекомендуют использовать com.google.api (v3) -  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java